# How to find scrollable elements in DOM using XPath?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, scrollbar, element

Basically I need to find all elements on the page that have a scrollbar (vertical or horizontal)

How to tell if an element has a scrollbar and can actually be scrolled? I found [this code snippet on jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-scrollable/2). Is it possible to capture the logic behind the code into and XPath expression? Or are there any other ways to check for scrollbars?

Added:

Just to explain what I'm trying to do: I'm developing [VimFx](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimfx/) - extension for Firefox. Basically it introduces Vim-style mouseless shortcuts (I know there is Vimperator and Pentadactyl...). One of the features I'd like to implement is to allow the use to select the container that's scrolled with j/k keys. That's why I need to discover all scrollable elements on any given random page.

Comment: XPath does not have access to information about how the element has been rendered, so this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with javscript is the overflow of a div is set to "scroll"

```
document.getElementById(elementId).style.overflow == "scroll";
```

I would check that on every element tough. If all of your elements are divs' then use this:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(index in allElements) {
  var element = allElements[index];
  if (element.style.overflow == "scroll" || element.style.overflowX == "scroll" || element.style.overflowY == "scroll"){
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to go the JS path.. The problem is that in my case any element might be scrollable...

Comment: This only works if scrollable elements are styled _inline_ to use `overflow: scroll`. Using `window.getComputedStyle()` would be better, but is very slow. Still, most scrollable elements have `overflow: auto`, which means that they have a scrollbar only if they need to. Then it’s still left to somehow determine if the element really _is_ scrollable or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have now implemented [support for discovering scrollable elements](https://github.com/akhodakivskiy/VimFx/commit/4a46193fea775d91968ebb3bc3c223263b741fa6) in VimFx.

The key to solving this problem is to use the Mozilla-specific events [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/overflow)
and [underflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/underflow).

The concept is:

```
// The function used for the overflow event:
function(event) {
  // `window` is a reference to the current window.
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(event.target)
  // `overflow: hidden` can cause overflow, but without a scrollbar, so
  // exclude such elements
  if (computedStyle && computedStyle.getPropertyValue('overflow') == 'hidden') {
    return
  }
  // `scrollableElements` is a reference to a `WeakMap` object for the
  // current window.
  scrollableElements.set(event.target)
}

// The function used for the underflow event:
function(event) {
  scrollableElements.delete(event.target)
}

// Somewhere else in the code we can now get a suitable `scrollableElements`
// object and check if elements are present in it.
if (scrollableElements.has(someElement)) {
  // `someElement` is scrollable!
}
```